# Swagger don't find Model without @RequestBody in post request

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I use springboot with swagger in my project.I have created a post method like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/ufile")
@Api(value = "文件服务", tags = {"文件服务"})
public class UfileController extends BaseApiController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UfileController.class);

    @ApiOperation(value = "文件上传", response = ApiResponse.class)
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public ApiResponse upload(@Valid @RequestBody UploadRequest uploadRequest, @ApiIgnore HttpServletResponse response
            , @RequestParam(value = "protocol", defaultValue = "thrift", required = false) @ApiIgnore String protocol) {
           .......
    }
}
```

I have use @RequestBody in model UploadRequest in above code.
And this is the model **UploadRequest**:

```
@Data
@ApiModel("文件上传请求")
public class UploadRequest extends BaseRequest {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "上传的文件", name = "上传的文件")
    @NotEmpty
    private MultipartFile[] multipartFiles;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "租户id", name = "租户id")
    @NotBlank
    private String tenantId;

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "图片是否需要对应水印图片", name = "图片是否需要对应水印图片")
    private boolean needWaterMark;
}
```

Swagger work well in this scene,it find ApiModel **UploadRequest**,and when I visit  swagger-ui.html.I can see that:
[image]

But when I don't use @RequestBody in model UploadRequest,swagger can't find **UploadRequest**.When I visit swagger-ui,there is no **UploadRequest** in **Model** label.
[image]

What I want is when I change my code like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ufile")
@Api(value = "文件服务", tags = {"文件服务"})
public class UfileController extends BaseApiController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UfileController.class);

    @ApiOperation(value = "文件上传", response = ApiResponse.class)
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = "application/json;charset=utf-8")
    public ApiResponse upload(@Valid UploadRequest uploadRequest, @ApiIgnore HttpServletResponse response
            , @RequestParam(value = "protocol", defaultValue = "thrift", required = false) @ApiIgnore String protocol) {

    }
}
```

swagger can still find ApiModel UploadRequest.when I visit swagger-ui.html,the label **Model** contains UploadRequest.

Who can help me,please.

Comment: Model shall be connected to any one of the requests, to be get displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement sounds kinda vague to me.
Btw, when you use `@RequestBody` annotation it simply binds your `Http` Request's body to your model object. So simply put, when you avoid that annotation, you are going to miss any `http` request's body content sent by a request, hence, you are not seeing that in swagger. That's it.
If you need more clarification or anything, please mention it.

Comment: what I want is when I don't use @RequestBody in model  UploadRequest,swagger still can find this ApiModel and still show in swagger-ui.html

Comment: unfortunately, that's not possible in this way without that annotation. But, instead, one thing can be done,  you can do that using `path variable` or `request param`, though I won't recommend for that